# Stop 24V DC motor rotation in one direction

Tags: power-electronics, dc-motor, automation

I am using a 24V DC motor in my application.

I would like to stop my 24DC motor rotation in one direction only i. e. suppose **the DC motor is rotating clockwise**, in my application, it may happen that **it is being rotated anti-clockwise by the user forcefully**.
Now, I would like to stop that from happening.

I am thinking of using some kind of electronic lock which will latch itself upon receiving an input but not sure about it.

The thing is, it is not supposed to rotate unidirectionally. It rotates in both directions. And when someone tries to rotate it in the direction it is not supposed to rotate forcefully, my sensors detect it and the controller is then supposed to send the command to the lock then.

**Any suggestions(I need something which will lock itself upon sensing something like this happening, not at all times)**!

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you have an electronic velocity/position control loop already? If yes, use that one. Otherwise, consider an electromagnetic brake that is released only when the motor is running. If it is enough to provide some resistance rather than a full lock, it might be enough to use a diode to short the motor winding when going in reverse. A mechanical ratchet might be simplest.

Comment: How forcefully? Because if the motor is only ever going to be driven uni-directionally, then a flyback diode in parallel with the motor would short it when it tries to motor in the opposite direction causing it to act as a generator. But this force would be speed dependent and ineffective at low speeds. It would just resist the user but not stop them.

Comment: Can you use a worm gear? Such as https://www.machinemfg.com/why-is-the-worm-gear-called-the-worm-gear/

Comment: use something like a spring clutch

Comment: @DKNguyen it isn't. It rotates in both ways. I have edited the question to add more clarity.

Comment: Then what polwel said about electronic control. Velocity and position control should do this inherently. If it's being told to do something it will resist external forces that oppose the thing it's trying to do.

Comment: What is your application?

Comment: @Bruce Abott, I am sorry I can't tell you that

Comment: Can you at least tell us what the motor specs are and how much torque it has to resist?

Comment: Once you have locked the motor, how will you decide to unlock it?

Comment: @DanielChisholm , that's why I am looking for a solution that would take digital signals for unlocking.

Answer (score 0):

If the electronics can sense operating conditions and control the motor at the same time then options are an electric friction brake; or solenoid locking mechanism (solenoid); or maybe switching in a generator braking resistor but that would not necessarily lock the position only increase the torque necessary to turn the shaft. If there is a large gearbox it may be difficult or impossible for a user to turn the output shaft and less braking resistance would be necessary to lock the shaft.